# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeff615'

Tags: python

so i am trying to read an input from a file, but i face this problem with reading from that file and throw this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\ufeff615'` so this is the code i am trying to execute:

```py
def testcase(number: int, solve_function):
    while (number != 0):
        solve_function()
        number -= 1

def map_input(datatype):
    return map(datatype, sys.stdin.readline().split())

sys.stdin = open('in', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('out', 'w')

def solve():
    D, P = map_input(int)
    T = D / P + 37
    print('%.3f'% T)

testcase(1, solve)
```

Input:(that is inside the `in` file i am reading from)

```
615 11
```

Expected Output:

```
92.909
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think `sys.stdin = open('in', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('out', 'w')` is doing? I am guessing your program would work better if you deleted these two lines.

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @Stef i can't comment those out cuz it will not be able to read from a file (in) or write to the file (out)

Comment: Can you add what is in the file `in`?

Comment: (1) I urge you to read the doc I linked which explains how to use `open` to read and write files without overwriting `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`. (2) It is likely the error you get is because of a problem with the encoding of your input file. Can you show the content of that file in your question?

Comment: If you are on unix, can you please show the content of the file `in` by typing the command `cat -A in` in the command line?

Comment: the input file contains two integers only ```615 11``` and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very conventional way to read from a file in python. I suggest reading the documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

After reading the documentation, you can replace this part from your code:

```py
def map_input(datatype):
    return map(datatype, sys.stdin.readline().split())

sys.stdin = open('in', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('out', 'w')
```

with a more conventional:

```py
def map_input(datatype):
    with open('in', 'r') as f:
        line = next(f)
    return map(datatype, line.split())
```

And likewise, replace your call to `print('%.3f'% T)` with:

```py
with open('out', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{:.3f}\n'.format(T))
```

Comment: Now we *should* be on Python 3, a neater solution to the last part would be `f'{T:.3f}\n'`

Comment: that make sense but still didn't work, i will read more about this in the docs you provided, thx <3

Comment: @NibrasShami I still believe the problem comes from encoding or invisible characters in your file `in`. What operating system are you on? Can you try to make a new file `in2` and run the code `with open('in2', 'r') as f: line = next(f); D,P = map(int, line.split())` to check if that works with the different file? It works fine on my computer. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @Stef yep, i was sussing the input file i made and when i made a new in file it worked perfectly, my code and your code was ok with no problems, it's just the input file, appreciate it <3

Answer (score 0):

I think input is supposed to be like int(map_input)
the int() goes before the variable

```
   def testcase(number: int, solve_function):
    while (number != 0):
        solve_function()
        number -= 1

def map_input(datatype):
    return map(datatype, sys.stdin.readline().split())

sys.stdin = open('in', 'r')
sys.stdout = open('out', 'w')

def solve():
    D, P = int(map_input)
    T = D / P + 37
    print('%.3f'% T)

testcase(1, solve)
```

try this maybe

Comment: That wouldn't work. `int` takes a single item and you're attempting to pass it a generator, it'd just throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue was from the input file I am reading from, the code i wrote and the code that @Stef wrote was right, I made another input file and it just worked well